# When to use “shadow-cljs release app” vs “shadow-cljs compile app”?

Tags: deployment, build, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

While building the web app for a new firebase deploy, I have been using:

```bash
$ shadow-cljs compile app
```

Actually, even clearing stuff and then re-compiling, such as:

```bash
$ rm -rf .shadow-cljs
$ shadow-cljs compile app
```

Apparently, the `release` command could also be used:

```bash
$ shadow-cljs release app
```

What is the difference between the two? What are the implications of each choice?
On a build before a new deployment, what would be the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compile` command builds a development version and exits: https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_development_mode

The `release` command builds a release version and exits: https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_release_mode

Comment: Is there any practical implication beyond the size/amount of files generated?

Comment: Too many to list in a comment. In short, a dev build is optimized for, well, development, including hot code reloading. A release build is optimized for performance and size.

Comment: Development builds should never leave the developers machine basically. So only `release` builds should be deployed or copied elsewhere.